# (Play 2.1.3) @select return (String, String) pair

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm struggling with @select helper in play 2.1.3.

I want to do a simple select with a list of users. The select should have the values set to the user's id and the option should have the name of the user.
I'm using the MongoDB module, so they're both strings.
Here's what I have:

```
@select(createForm("userId"),
    options = User.options(),
    'class -> "form-control",
    '_default -> "--- Select ---",
        '_label -> "User assigned",
        '_showConstraints -> false
)
```

and options() in User model:

```
public static Seq<java.util.Map.Entry<String,String>> options() {

    Seq<java.util.Map.Entry<String, String>> map = new Seq<java.util.Map.Entry<String,String>>();

    for (User user : User.coll.find().toArray()) {

        //seq.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String>(user.id, user.name));
    }

    return map;
}
```

the error is:

```
type mismatch; found : Seq[java.util.Map.Entry[String,String]] required: Seq[(String, String)]
```

How can I define a pair of strings like that? (String, String), or is there a simpler way to do that without the loop?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, a `(String, String)` in Java is a `scala.Tuple2<String, String>`, so your Seq should look like a `Seq<Tuple2<String, String>>`

You may use the `play.libs.Scala` helper to perform conversions between Java and Scala types:

```
List<Tuple2<String, String>> values = new ArrayList<>();
for (User user : User.coll.find().toArray()) {
    values.add(Scala.Tuple("asd", "zxc"));
}
return Scala.toSeq(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you @serejja for your answer.

I found another way of getting to the same result, that is with using the options helper as I like using the scala.* packages as less as possible.

```
public static java.util.Map<String,String> options() {
    java.util.Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    for (User user : User.coll.find().toArray()) {

        map.put(user.id, user.name);
    }
}
```

and then in scala:

```
@select(createForm("userId"),
    options = options(User.options()),
    'class -> "form-control",
    '_default -> "--- Select ---",
    '_label -> "User assigned",
    '_showConstraints -> false
```

)

note the **options = options(User.options())** part.

However, I guess @serejja's way is a more "native" Scala solution. So I'm counting his as the answer.

Thank you once again.